# Wallet integration in React native Android application

Tags: android, react-native, payment-processing, wallet

I have use case for my react native application. To promote my application I want create a referral and reward program. Where whoever download my application using the referral code will get the x points in the application and the person who has referred him will get the y points, and I want user should be able to redeem this points and convert it to rupees.

I could find any solution for this points to rupees conversion solution.

I want solution for the wallet integration in React native Android application where I should be able to convert user loyalty points to rupees.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.